# ROS Wiki Citation

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

What would be the correct way to cite to ROS-wiki? In a bibtex entry who should the author be, since it a community wiki?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63935/ros-wiki-citation/) by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use @misc without an author http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page

Wikipedia has [some good recommendations too](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aCite&page=LaTeX&id=413720397)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-11-13**:
As in Stage, recommendation is to cite this paper 'Richard Vaughan. "Massively Multiple Robot Simulations in Stage", Swarm Intelligence 2(2-4):189-208, 2008. Springer.', Could be cited this paper (http://www.willowgarage.com/papers/ros-open-source-robot-operating-system) in the case of ROS?